# How to use AC_CONFIG_COMMANDS_PRE and AC_CONFIG_COMMANDS_POST?

Tags: autotools, autoconf

The [Autoconf manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.60/html_node/Configuration-Commands.html) discusses the `AC_CONFIG_COMMANDS_PRE` and `AC_CONFIG_COMMANDS_PRE` macros (shown below).

When I use the macros in the following relative order they are not applied:

```
## configure.ac
...

AC_OUTPUT(Makefile)
AC_CONFIG_COMMANDS_POST(cmd)
AC_CONFIG_COMMANDS_POST(cmd)
AC_CONFIG_COMMANDS_POST(cmd)
```

When I change the relative order:

```
AC_CONFIG_COMMANDS_POST([sed -e '|S["CC"]|d' config.status > config.status.xxx; mv config.status.xxx config.status])
AC_CONFIG_COMMANDS_POST([sed -e '|S["FLAGS"]|d' config.status > config.status.xxx; mv config.status.xxx config.status])
AC_CONFIG_COMMANDS_POST([sed -e '|S["ac_ct_CC"]|d' config.status > config.status.xxx; mv config.status.xxx config.status])
AC_OUTPUT(Makefile)
```

Then it results in:

```
configure: creating ./config.status
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `|'
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `|'
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `|'
```

My first question is, what is the format of `cmd`? Should it be wrapped in brackets (`[` and `]`) like `AC_CONFIG_COMMANDS`? Or does it need something else?

My second question is, what is the relative order of the macros `AC_OUTPUT`, `AC_CONFIG_COMMANDS_PRE` and `AC_CONFIG_COMMANDS_POST`?

My third question is, at what point is `config.status` or `Makefile` written so I can fix it?

There is also a section in the manual [3.1.3 Standard configure.ac Layout](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.61/html_node/configure_002eac-Layout.html#configure_002eac-Layout), but it does not discuss the relative ordering of `AC_OUTPUT`, `AC_CONFIG_COMMANDS_PRE` and `AC_CONFIG_COMMANDS_POST`.

I prefer to fix the `Makefile`, but my reading of the manual seems to indicate we are called when `config.status` is ready, and not when the `Makefile` is ready.

Thanks in advance.

---

> ```
> — Macro: AC_CONFIG_COMMANDS (tag..., [cmds], [init-cmds])
>
>     Specify additional shell commands to run at the end of config.status, and 
>     shell commands to initialize any variables from configure. Associate the 
>     commands with tag. Since typically the cmds create a file, tag should 
>     naturally be the name of that file. If needed, the directory hosting tag is 
>     created. This macro is one of the instantiating macros; see Configuration 
>     Actions.
>
>     Here is an unrealistic example:
>
>               fubar=42
>               AC_CONFIG_COMMANDS([fubar],
>                                  [echo this is extra $fubar, and so on.],
>                                  [fubar=$fubar])
>
>  — Macro: AC_CONFIG_COMMANDS_PRE (cmds)
>
>     Execute the cmds right before creating config.status.
>
>     This macro presents the last opportunity to call AC_SUBST, AC_DEFINE, or
>     AC_CONFIG_FOOS macros. 
>
> — Macro: AC_CONFIG_COMMANDS_POST (cmds)
>
>     Execute the cmds right after creating config.status.
> ```

Comment: As for the `sed` errors, you seem to be trying to use the pipe symbol, `|`, as a regular expression delimiter in your addresses.  The ordinary delimiter is the forward slash (`/`).  To use a different one, you must precede it with a backslash: `sed -e '\|S["CC"]|d' config.status [...]`.

Answer (score 2):

> My third question is, at what point is config.status or Makefile written so I can fix it?

[`AC_OUTPUT`](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/autoconf.html#Output).  `config.status` should actually [instantiate](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/autoconf.html#config_002estatus-Invocation) your template files.  For example:

```
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_CONFIG_COMMANDS_PRE([echo ---- pre config.status])
AC_CONFIG_COMMANDS([tag], [echo ---- at end of config.status])
AC_CONFIG_COMMANDS_POST([echo ---- post config.status])
AC_OUTPUT
```

I get

```
---- pre config.status
configure: creating ./config.status
---- post config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing tag commands
---- at end of config.status
```

So it looks like `AC_CONFIG_COMMANDS` is where you want to perform your Makefile fixups, and `AC_CONFIG_COMMANDS_POST` is where you want to perform your config.status fixups.  This is what I was expecting given the documentation.  This should answer your second question as well.

> Then it results in: [*sed errors*]

Try:

```
AC_CONFIG_COMMANDS_POST([sed -e '/S\[["CC"\]]/d' config.status > config.status.xxx; mv config.status.xxx config.status])
AC_CONFIG_COMMANDS_POST([sed -e '/S\[["FLAGS"\]]/d' config.status > config.status.xxx; mv config.status.xxx config.status])
AC_CONFIG_COMMANDS_POST([sed -e '/S\[["ac_ct_CC"\]]/d' config.status > config.status.xxx; mv config.status.xxx config.status])
```

You might consider [GNU shtool](https://www.gnu.org/software/shtool/) as a portable `sed` wrapper, as it can do replacement (and a bunch of other stuff you might find useful (or overkill)).

Comment: Thanks @ldav1s. I thought `config.status` produces the `Makefile` (I think John Bollinger told me that a while back). If so, it seems like using `AC_CONFIG_COMMANDS` on  `Makefile` would be incorrect. Thanks for the `GNU shtool` hint. I don't think we will be able to use it because of some less popular platforms we support, like AIX, OSX and Solaris. The tool is not going to be available.

Comment: `config.status` does produce the template files (e.g. Makefile).  `AC_CONFIG_COMMANDS` runs at the end of all that (see above).  The point of `shtool` is you include it (it's a shell script) as part of your source dist, not as something that is required to be installed by the user.  `shtool` does seem to support AIX, Darwin and Solaris.

Comment: And this seems largely to answer the OP's first question as well.  The `cmd` argument is a shell "list".  Moreover, substantially *every* argument to every Autoconf macro should be quoted (to Autoconf/`m4`) by enclosing it in square brackets (`[]`).